# On-prem Self-hosted integration runtime to Azure-Datafactory through Azure Expressroute

Tags: azure, data-migration, azure-data-factory

I have a VM, that is onprem and has Selfhosted IR which is connected to a Datafactory. Now the onprem network is connected to azure via azure Expressroute.

1. What to do if I want data to be transferred from onprem to azure datalake through datafactory pipeline by making use of that expressroute?
2. When I connect datafactory to a private endpoint in a VNet that is connected to Az-Expressroute, why does self integration run time node goes offline?